# Any good solutions for a .htaccess redirect to a subfolder without changing the url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect from the root to a subfolder using .htaccess and I either get 500 or a redirect loop.

I'm working on a HMVC framework and I need to be able to break sections(folders) of the site into their own code islands.
Some of witch will use the framework some will use open source software (OpenCart,Wordpress..)

Folder structure(root):

```
 /index
 /shop
 /blog
 .htaccess
```

When the root is accessed I need it to be redirected to /index(or any other subfolder) from the .htaccess file without changing the url.

These folders have their own .htaccess file.

The redirect from the root needs to run .htaccess inside the subfolder(most frameworks need mod_rewrite)

This...

```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:\/\/radu\.koding\.com\/$1 [L,NC]
  RewriteRule ^$ index [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index/$1 [L]
```

doesn't seem to work. I'm caught in a redirect loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^index/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index/$1 [L]
```

This RewriteCond compares what the RewriteRule matched against not beginning with `index/`.

(I skipped the second RewriteRule in your original example here – redirecting “nothing” to `index/` should work fine.)

Comment: Thanks, but I still get 500.

Comment: All this hassle cause I didn't want to duplicate code. My dilemma can be avoided by routing the root **.htaccess** to an index.php file(still in the root) that points to the framework in the **/index** folder. Maybe this is a compromise that I have to live with.